# Creating Single Page App in Django with Polymer

Tags: django, polymer

I'm currently working on a singe page app in django that makes use of Polymer Elements. My problem  is when I'm changing template views.

When I click on a page link to direct me to a new view I want to use the `app-route`, `app-location` and the `iron-pages` elements that Polymer has. This lets me simply change my current views without actually having to reload the whole page again and make requests. Apparently, in Django, whenever I click on a link it instead goes to the `urls.py` and tries to direct me to that link. Is it possible to create single page apps in django with polymer?

Comment: The answer is yes definitely. Are you sure there is no error?

Comment: @user2438933 Yes I'm definitely sure. I'm thinking the the cause why my urls are being read by django instead of in the app-route is because my current app is inside the django app. I should separate the two and use django instead to serve my app-shell instead of having my whole app within django.

Comment: You said "my current app is inside the django app" what does it mean? Would you mind to show me some code. Thanks

Comment: What I meant was that my app is a django app. I should create a separate app that's only based in polymer and have django host that app.