# Routing with Polymer and Django

Tags: django, django-templates, polymer, polymer-2.x

I am trying to set up an app using Polymer/Django. I have one template that basically exists to instantiate my base component (admin-panel), which works rather swell. The trouble is that now the  that I use inside my component doesn't pick up any changes! What gives?

Here's my template:

```
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="{% static 'index.html' %}"/>
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- Load webcomponents-loader.js to check and load any polyfills your browser needs -->
    <script src="{% static 'bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js' %}"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="{% static 'src/admin-panel.html' %}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <admin-panel></admin-panel>
</body>
```

My Django urlpatterns all resolve to the above template:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?!api).*$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

And here's the  part of my admin-panel component:

```
<app-location
    route="{{route}}"
    url-space-regex="^[[rootPath]]">
</app-location>

<app-route
    route="{{route}}"
    pattern="[[rootPath]]:page"
    data="{{routeData}}"
    tail="{{query}}">
</app-route>

<app-drawer-layout fullbleed narrow="{{narrow}}">

  <!-- Main content -->
  <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>
    ... stuff ...

    <iron-pages
        selected="[[page]]"
        attr-for-selected="name"
        fallback-selection="not-found-page"
        role="main">
      <landing-page name="landing-page"></landing-page>
      <organization-detail-page 
          name="organization-detail-page"
          route="[[query]]">
      </organization-detail-page>
      <not-found-page name="not-found-page"></not-found-page>
    </iron-pages>
  </app-header-layout>
</app-drawer-layout>
```

Anyone else used app-route with django templates? What did you do?

Comment: This is a duplicate of
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47342880/creating-single-page-app-in-django-with-polymer

But that was never answered

Comment: You're not getting a 404 on Django's urls?